# Cannot access memory at address in C - purposeful pointer corruption

Tags: c, memory

This is a programming challenge. I have to handle a corrupted char*.
How can we handle this in C.
Handle meaning: Not to SIGSEGV and quietly exit with a return code of -1

Here is the sample program:

```
int main() {
   char* corrupted = (char*)0xffffffffffffffff;
   char tmp[20];

   memcpy(tmp, corrupted, 20);
   printf("Copied\n");
   return 0;
}
```

I have tried the following :

```
if(!corrupted+1)
   memcpy(tmp, corrupted, 20);   // This works 5 out of 10 times

if(sizeof(*corrupted) <= 1)
```

Usually the memory block will have a string of one or more characters and sizeof does not crash instead it provides 8 for `sizeof(corrupted)` and 1 for `sizeof(*corrupted)` which makes sense.

I have tried `mincore` also, but I am not able to get it to work. Thank you very much.

```
unsigned long *p;
 if((mincore(p , 10, corrupted)) == -1){
      printf("mincore failed with error: %s", strerror(errno));
      return -1; 
 }
```

Comment: When it doesn't "work", what happens?

Comment: Since corrupted is a pointer, its size is 8.   Since it points to a char, the size of *corrupted is 1.  Both of these are constants at compile time, not calculated when the program runs.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to detect if a pointer is corrupt? Or ...?

Comment: "I have to handle" What would "handle" mean here? Best thing is to avoid dereferencing it. Is your challenge to detect that the pointer is corrupted? Or what is the expected outcome?

Comment: unsigned long *p;

if((mincore(p , 10, corrupted)) == -1){
        printf("mincore failed with error: %s", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
        }


This fails with "invalid argument". But this fails for good values of char* corrupted as well.

Comment: Sir, The expected outcome is not SEG FAULT and quietly exit the program if the char* is corrupted. If not, print the char* and return 0. Thank you.

Comment: Define "corrupted".

Comment: *This is a programming challenge.*  A fundamentally broken challenge, at that.  If memory is corrupted, nothing is reliable.  And how do you define a "corrupted" pointer so you can detect it in the first place?

Comment: char* corrupted = (char*)0xffffffffffffffff; 

You can run the sample code provided it will crash. Therefore this pointer or address cannot be accessed and will cause a crash. The question is "Can we fix the challenge". Thank you for your help.

Comment: What OS and CPU architecture? C language knows nothing about SIGSEGV, memory access permission etc. In some OSes you could read process memory map and check if the pointer points to a valid area. But it doesn't s guaranee the pointer is valid.

Comment: Thank you Dimich. 

OS - Reptilian on Ubuntu 
Arch - X86 ..

If you can point me to read process memory map, it will really help, I am researching that as well. Thank you.

Comment: @KudmiSubba `/proc/self/maps`

Comment: `sizeof(*corrupted)` will not give the length of the string referenced\]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to handle this is to register a [signal handler](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html), which is called when a `SIGSEGV` happens and can handle it. Something like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void signal_handler(int signum) {
  if(signum == SIGSEGV) {
    exit(-1);
  }
}

int main() {
  signal(SIGSEGV, signal_handler); // Register the signal handler

  char* corrupted = (char*)0xffffffffffffffff;
  char tmp[20];
  memcpy(tmp, corrupted, 20);
  printf("Copied\n");
  return 0;
}
```

This is going to be linux-specific, but since you mention SIGSEGV it looks like a fair guess to make.

Comment: yes , this indeed worked. I knew about signal handler, but I never thought of using it for this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: `printf()` is not listed as signal-safe function. Don't call it from signal handler.

Comment: @dimich Thank you for pointing that out, I didn't think about it. I removed it from the code.

Comment: As mentioned in the man page you linked [`signal(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) should be avoided and [`sigaction(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) used in its place.